# Listbox getting `Key` events with diacritics instead of national characters

Tags: python, tkinter, keypress, tk-toolkit

When I switch the keyboard to Russian layout, my widget gets key events with some diacritics in `keysym` instead of Russian letters.

Here's a demonstration (using the [`dump` module](https://github.com/native-api/dump)):

```
import Tkinter as tkinter
from dump import dump

def show_event(e):
    dump(e)

root=tkinter.Tk()
lb = tkinter.Listbox(root)
lb.grid()
root.bind_class('Listbox','<Control-Key>', show_event)
root.mainloop()
```

Now, when I focus the listbox and press `Ctrl` with letters `фыва` (that correspond to `asdf`), the `keysym`s in the printed events are: `ocircumflex`,`ucircumflex`,`acircumflex`,`agrave`.

While I, naturally, expected to get [`Cyrillic_ef`, `Cyrillic_yeru`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TkCmd/keysyms.htm) etc.

At the same time, if I type text into an `Entry`, Russian letters are inserted correctly.

Any ideas of what is going on & how to fix? That said, maybe it doesn't even *need* fixing (it may allow one to use the same binding for any non-English keyboard layout) but I'd still like to know the reason for this highly counterintuitive effect incl. if it's by design.

Answer (score 1):

From what I've found, it depends on what system you're working with. It seems like from the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14455625/tkinter-international-bind), for Windows you have to hack together things like `'<Control-ntilde>'` in key bindings, so you might be able to do `'<Control-ocircumflex>'`, `'<Control-ucircumflex>'`, ...

In OSX, I'm not even sure how to go about this. I tried the example that works for Windows and wasn't able to get it to register the keypresses.  And for Linux, I haven't been able to try.

**EDIT:** To actually answer your question, essentially when Tk translates virtual key codes delivered by the system to the Tk window, it uses the function `TkpGetKeySym()`, which in turn calls Windows `ToAscii()` function. This function will take into account the current active keymap when processing even though it's only designed to return codes of Latin-1 characters. The specific keymap for Russian is [Windows-1251](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1251), which is used when `TkpGetKeySym()` is called but the caller interprets the outputs as if they're Latin-1. Is there a fix? It seems not. I've basically just (attempted to) summarize what's from [this page](https://chiselapp.com/user/sgolovan/repository/tkabber-wiki/doc/tip/wiki/ru/Tk_Windows_keysyms_bug_explained.md), so I'd suggest reading it for a more in-depth explanation and to check if I misread anything.

Comment: _"so you might be able to do '<Control-ocircumflex>', '<Control-ucircumflex>'"_ -- I already figured out that much. I'd like to know where these strange symbols are coming from (perhaps some "default" layout?) and if something can be done about them. Also why just inputting national characters works correctly at the same time.

Comment: I've edited my answer to answer your questions. Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Now you're talking! Although the info is a bit obsolete: since https://github.com/tcltk/tk/commit/b95cd239d1b396c8d302561387003af38bdd0a5c (8.6.7+), `ToAscii` is replaced by `ToUnicode`.

Comment: I've been searching for the past few days within the source and haven't been able to find why though I'd guess the caller is interpreting the unicode wrong but my guess is as good as any? I'll be gone for the next few weeks, so there won't be an answer soon.